# cURL on own URL not working. unable to get any response

Tags: php, rest, curl, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress plugin for my site. In the Plugin, there is a piece of code that is supposed to hit a service that is again hosted on my own site.

the reason for this self call is that the plugin should be later on redistributed to other WordPress sites owned by me...

The service is perfectly working when the service is deployed on the production website and is tested from the plugin installed in the local dummy installation of WordPress site.

when the same plugin is installed in the Production site, the response comes as null. Unable to get any kind of response on the same.

I am using the below code to call the REST Service. Method is POST.

```
function callAPI($method, $url,$headers, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }
    // Optional Authentication:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}
```

As per expectation, if I call the URL and just echo out some dump data, then also the data does not show up as response.

I am able to test the service from the Google Chrome extension for REST Testing as well

Comment: the code for the service seems more relevant thatn the code for the curl request..

Comment: in other words, you should post the code that is returning an unexpected result, not the code which is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you can test the same call with a Google Chrome extension and it works fine, most likely something goes wrong with your cURL calls. You should check if `$result` is `FALSE` or not, and if it is then use [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) for more information on what happened.

**Update:**

From the documentation:

> To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path.

You have to escape the `@` sign and it'll work.

Comment: I can get the error as " couldn't open file XXXX" the XXXX is sent as a data in post field  as "@XXXX"...should it affect the system..??

Comment: What is XXXX exactly? Clearly, it cannot access that file because of some reason.

Comment: It's a twitter handle that I am sending across...if I am sending without the @...then it's working fine in production also...where as it's working fine with and without in local

Comment: You should use `http_build_query` on `$data` because the `@` sign as the first character indicates that it's a file so you have to escape it, or just remove it.

Comment: I don't know why it's working on your local environment, but you have to escape it according to the documentation to send the data properly. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I think that should do it...will test it in a while and post accordingly